# App opens automatically when receives broadcast

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

i have a big problem on my app.

When it's closed (not in background) and it receives a broadcast the app is **open** and put on **foreground**.

It's very annoying.

I put the **same** broadcast receiver's code in an empty project and the problem doesn't arise.

The **upper** code is copied in AndroidMonitor when the receivers is activated by the app that have the bug.

The **lower** with the app that doesn't have problem.

```html
09-18 12:28:34.893 26455-26455/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-18 12:28:34.960 26455-26455/agm.fisioapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/agm.fisioapp-2/lib/arm
09-18 12:28:35.063 26455-26455/agm.fisioapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-18 12:28:35.141 26455-26455/agm.fisioapp D/AutoManageHelper: starting AutoManage for client 0 false false
09-18 12:28:35.160 26455-26455/agm.fisioapp D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaa$zza@945134}
09-18 12:28:35.206 26455-26499/agm.fisioapp I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (Ia6c73e7530)
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
                                                          Build Date: 12/04/15 Fri
                                                          Local Branch: mybranch17080070
                                                          Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.5
                                                          Local Patches: NONE
                                                          Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
09-18 12:28:35.215 26455-26499/agm.fisioapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-18 12:28:35.215 26455-26499/agm.fisioapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-18 12:28:35.217 26455-26499/agm.fisioapp W/Adreno-ES20: <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
09-18 12:28:35.250 26455-26491/agm.fisioapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
09-18 12:28:35.252 26455-26491/agm.fisioapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

09-18 12:30:35.063 28050-28050/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-18 12:30:35.086 28050-28057/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-18 12:30:35.086 28050-28057/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
09-18 12:30:35.104 28050-28050/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.javatechig.alarmservice-2/lib/arm
09-18 12:30:35.113 28050-28050/? D/prova: prova
```

This is the receiver's code:

```
public class CreatoreNotificaAllenamento extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    long[] pattern = {0, 500, 1};
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 01234, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icona_notifica)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notifica_titolo_ricordo_allenamnto))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.testo_notifica))
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And this is the method i use to start the AlarmService:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context c, Date data) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(c, CreatoreNotificaAllenamento.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, intent, 0);

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() > data.getTime()) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(data);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        data = cal.getTime();
    }
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, data.getTime(),
            1000*60*2, pi);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="agm.fisioapp">
/*
PERMESSI
*/
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icona"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".Algoritmi.CreatoreNotificaAllenamento" />
    <receiver android:name=".Algoritmi.SampleBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    /*
     other activities
    */

</application>
```

App.java code:

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    SharedPreferences primoAvvio = getSharedPreferences(Costanti.preferenzeMiste, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!primoAvvio.contains("primoAvvio")) {
        // se entro qua vuol dire che è il primo avvio dell'app
        try {
            caricaDatiSulDB();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = primoAvvio.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("primoAvvio", false);
            editor.apply();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else try{
        MainModel model = new MainModel(getApplicationContext());
        if(controlloVersione()) {
            model.cancellaDati();
            caricaDatiSulDB();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Controlla se l'utente è loggato.
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Costanti.preferenzeDatiUtente, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!prefs.contains("idUtente") && prefs.getBoolean("isGoogle",false) == false){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    } else {
        // se esistono dei dati di login salvati eseguilo in background.
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundLogin.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
}

/**
 * Controlla se va fatto l'aggiornamento degli es/patologie/ecc..
 * @return true se va aggiornato, false altrimenti
 */
private boolean controlloVersione() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("version.txt")));
    float version = Float.parseFloat(in.readLine());
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Costanti.preferenzeMiste, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(version != preferences.getFloat("versione", 0)){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putFloat("versione", version);
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

private void caricaDatiSulDB() throws IOException {
    MainModel model = new MainModel(getApplicationContext());
    // carico i dati nel db locale
    model.eserciziToDB(model.lettura(FILE_ESERCIZI));
    model.patologieToDB(model.lettura(FILE_PATOLOGIE));
    model.protocolliToDB(model.lettura(FILE_PROTOCOLLI));
    model.faseToDB(model.lettura(FILE_FASI));
    model.defaultToDB(model.lettura(FILE_ESERCIZIO_FASI));
    model.consigliToDB(model.lettura(FILE_CONSIGLIO));
    model.specificheToDB(model.lettura(FILE_SPECIFICHE));
    model.curiositaToDB(model.lettura(FILE_CURIOSITA));
}
```

}

Comment: How are you registering/unregistering your BroadcastReceiver? post that code also

Comment: Hi @AlexTa! I register the BroadcastReceiver in manifest. See the post! ;-)

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense to me at all. There must be something else going on that is starting your app and bringing it to the foreground.

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes, it's has no sense. But this occurs only when receivers are activated. The same is for SampleBootReceiver (it starts on device startup).

Comment: Wait...you have a custom `Application` class called `App`. Please post the code for that!

Comment: @DavidWasser edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected. When your app is not running, and a `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered (for example, at BOOT time), Android creates a new OS process for your app and creates a new instance of your custom `Application` class, and calls `onCreate()` on that instance. In your code, call `startActivity()` inside `onCreate()` of your custom `Application` class. This will, of course, bring your app to the foreground and show the `Activity` that was started. You probably don't want that to happen.

You should probably remove the `startActivity()` calls from `onCreate()` of your custom `Application` class and put them some other place.

Answer (score 0):

@BertoGT

The reason why your app open automatically when receive a broadcast because you have define your broadcast in manifest file.

To solve your problem, you have to register for the broad cast receiver in your class.Then register broadcast receiver in on onResume method and unregister the broadcast receiver on onPause or onDestroy method.Your problem will be solved.